# How to show the coordinates of a point in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to find the coordinates of a vertex (aka corner) of a shape (aka polygon) in Adobe Illustrator CC 2017.  I tried using the Window -> Info view but that showed me the same coordinates for every vertex of the shape (source: [How to show the coordinates of point handles in Adobe Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28411/how-to-show-the-coordinates-of-point-handles-in-adobe-illustrator)).

How do I find the coordinates of a point in Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see coordinates of a vertex of a shape by going to Window -> Control in Adobe Illustrator CC 2017.  And when I clicked on different vertices, the coordinates changed unlike with Window -> Info.

Comment: It's been the same a long time before the CC.